# keep me/her/him to oneself vs keep oneself to oneself vs keep to oneself

Tags: grammaticality

The [latter two](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keep_to_oneself) are correct and one may more easily come across them than at a phrase as *I keep me to myself.* .
Being a big fan of efficiency, **me / her / him** have less syllables than has **myself / herself / himself**, I cannot but wonder whether,

**1.** *I keep me to myself.* is correct?

**2.** Is *I keep me to myself.* idiomatic (provided that it is correct)? Some of the research that I've done suggests that it is not.
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keeps+me+to+myself%2C+keeps+myself+to+myself&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kept+me+to+myself%2C+kept+myself+to+myself&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=me+to+myself%2Cmyself+to+myself&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10&case_insensitive=true

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=her+to+herself%2C+herself+to+herself&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keeps+her+to+herself%2Ckeeps+herself+to+herself&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10

Comment: "I keep to myself" seems the most natural with "me", although with the third person it's maybe different. (Note that just posting a link to a search doesn't really indicate research: explain what you found.)

Comment: *Keep* can be reflexive ("The cat keeps itself clean") but it is not reflexive when the phrase is "keep to himself".  At least not in *spoken* American English. I have read that phrase but have never ever heard it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly half of the examples of "keeps to himself" in the most recent tranche (2012 - 2019) Google ngrams turns up are false positives (transitive, of the form

- ... *it means that what he keeps to himself is better than what he shows* ...
- ... *I mean that part of it which the owner keeps to himself* ... )

[image]

but the relevant examples

> Example from Google search, given with Farlex definition of 'keep to
> oneself':
>
> - *The old man down the street always keeps to himself. I just realized I don't even know his name.* [[Farlex Dictionary of
>   Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keeps+to+himself)]

still outnumber those for the equally acceptable (if slightly old-fashioned) reflexive usage 'keeps himself to himself'.

> Example from ngrams:
>
> - ... *the rigid silence of one who keeps himself to himself* ... [[The Essential Works of Georg Wilhelm
>   Hegel](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Essential_Works_of_Georg_Wilhelm_Fri/7LfoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22keeps+himself+to+himself%22&pg=PT451&printsec=frontcover)]

But 'Keeps him to himself' is so unidiomatic I'd say it's ungrammatical, like 'He shaves him every morning' when meaning 'He shaves himself every morning'.